# The difference between two java.sql.Time objects measured in minutes

Tags: java, sql, time

I need to know the difference between two java.sql.Time objects and the difference must be measured in minutes.
This is how I do it:

```
java.sql.Time srTime = sr.getTime(); // 12:40:04
java.sql.Time chTime = ch.getTime(); // 12:32:00
long diff = Math.abs(srTime.getTime() - chTime.getTime()); // 484000
```

The result (`diff`) is equal to 484000. How to make it equal to 8 minutes?

Comment: Use division `int result = 484000 / 1000 /* take out milliseconds */ / 60 /* convert to minutes */; System.out.println(result);`.

Comment: Its in milliseconds...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use division

```
int result =   484000
             / 1000   /* take out milliseconds */ 
             / 60     /* convert to minutes    */;
System.out.println(result);
```

Output:
     **8**

Answer (score 2):

You can simply divide it like this:

```
long diff = Math.abs(srTime.getTime() - chTime.getTime());
long res = diff/60000;
```

The diff which you are getting is in milliseconds, so you need to divide it by 60000 to get that in minutes.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using java 1.7 you can use the TimeUnit object.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html

Once you are getting a response um milliseconds, look at this example

```
long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(diff);
long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(diff);
```